# how do i achive social share like this site when mobile device having low resolution ? i used 100% width container but social icon went outside Screen

Tags: html, css

[with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq2Eb.jpg)  [want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF2Q2.jpg) I used below CSS and want this site like button went down with low resolution devices please look attached image you will get better way what  i mean to say

https://www.shoutmeloud.com/best-keyword-research-tools-niche.html

`

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    align-items: stretch;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need 2 things:
1- Add the property `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the parent container to allow the childs to break into a new line
2- You need to add the properties `flex-grow: 1;` and `flex-shrink: 1;` to the direct child to allow the items to fill the gaps. Or alternatively use `flex: 1;`.

You can set a `min-width` for the links also

A working example:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  align-items: stretch;

  /* Needed property for the parent */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container a {
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  background: #4488ff;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;

  /* Needed for the child */
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
  <a href="#">6</a>
  <a href="#">7</a>
  <a href="#">8</a>
  <a href="#">9</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
  <a href="#">6</a>
  <a href="#">7</a>
  <a href="#">8</a>
  <a href="#">4</a>
  <a href="#">5</a>
  <a href="#">6</a>
  <a href="#">7</a>
  <a href="#">8</a>
  <a href="#">9</a>
</div>
```